# Difference in sizes shown by du -sh and ls -al

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, disk-space

I copied a zip file from a mounted drive to my VM. Now when I compare the sizes, using `du -sh` there is a difference of 900mb, with the copy on my VM being less in size.

However, when I do `ls -al`, the number of bytes for both the zips are a perfect match.

> I am confused, as to whether the copy operation was successful or not?
>
> Why is there a discrepancy here ?

**Edit** : Adding outputs. The files were copied using rsync. The VM is running Ubuntu 18.02.

**Using du -sh**

```
~/mountedVM# du -sh dev_preview.zip
7.5G dev_preview.zip

~# du -sh dev_preview.zip
6.6G dev_preview.zip
```

**Using ls -al**

```
~/mountedVM# ls -al
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root  6986744975 Aug 29 09:17 dev_preview.zip

~# ls -al
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 6986744975 Aug 30 10:09 dev_preview.zip
```

Comment: Please provide the output from the commands as typed, maybe your VM type?

Comment: @nyov I have added the requested information

Comment: Related: [Why are there so many different ways to measure disk usage?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120311/why-are-there-so-many-different-ways-to-measure-disk-usage) (unix.stackexchange)

Comment: Thanks. That is interesting... I'm hesitant to say if this is the result of your VM hypervisor doing data-deduplication, I'd think that would be opaque to the VM(?); or the result of using different filesystems. Anyway, @Hannu is correct that `du` shows actual space usage. Compare with `du -hs --apparent-size` instead. _Verify file contents by checksumming_ (`md5sum`/`crc32` is good enough here, and cheaper/faster than `shaXsum`) both files, and you can be certain that they are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filesystems may use e.g. sparse or by other means 'compressed' files to store the content of a file. The actual amount of disk space used is then reported by disk/partition/hardware related utilities, e.g. fdisk, du, ...

File related utilities (e.g. ls, wc, ...) should report the amount of data in the file, in uncompressed form.

Compare to how a file archival utility, e.g. those that create zip, rar, 7zip, and tar.gz archives, list info about the space occupied by an archived file.

Verify the content of a file with e.g.

```
$ sha1sum --help
Usage: sha1sum [OPTION]... [FILE]...
Print or check SHA1 (160-bit) checksums.
...

$ sha1sum ubuntu-16.04.6-desktop-amd64.iso >chksums.txt

$ cat chksums.txt 
a09607901183ab25c675626024aa402663fa2558  ubuntu-16.04.6-desktop-amd64.iso

$ sha1sum -c chksums.txt
ubuntu-16.04.6-desktop-amd64.iso: OK

$ time sha1sum ubuntu-16.04.6-desktop-amd64.iso 
a09607901183ab25c675626024aa402663fa2558  ubuntu-16.04.6-desktop-amd64.iso
3.004 seconds elapsed, p=100.00, 3.004 real, 2.852 user, 0.152 sys.

$ wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/SHA1SUMS
...

$ sha1sum -c SHA1SUMS
ubuntu-16.04.6-desktop-amd64.iso: OK
...

$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | sort | uniq | grep model
model       : 60
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770K CPU @ 3.50GHz
```

Comment: A zip file, as the op has, is unlikely to be [sparse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file), as it has no empty space. That would defeat the purpose of compression.

Comment: Please note that what I listed was not meant to be sparse zip files; there WAS an "or" between those two words. Text now changed to be more general.

Comment: @Hannu I did compare the checksum and they are the same. Seems like the copy is correct. Though, really cant understand why du is giving these differences